# cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId while making build on ionic4 with capacitor

Tags: firebase, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor

error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
^
symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
location: package com.google.firebase.iid

String currentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
^
symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId

String id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();
^
symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId

ng token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
^
symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Firebase updated their messaging library.

For this you need to update your firebase_messaging tp 10.0.0 in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem for Flutter Android